# Warning message in R when using colClasses when reading csv files

Tags: r, lapply, read.csv

I am using lapply to read a list of files. The files have multiple rows and columns, and I interested in the first row in the first column. The code I am using is:

```
lapply(file_list, read.csv,sep=',', header = F, col.names=F, nrow=1, colClasses = c('character', 'NULL', 'NULL'))
```

The first row has three columns but I am only reading the first one. From other posts on stackoverflow I found that the way to do this would be to use `colClasses = c('character', 'NULL', 'NULL')`. While this approach is working, I would like to know the underlying issue that is causing the following error message to be generated and hopefully prevent it from popping up:

> "In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
>     cols = 1 != length(data) = 3"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's to let you know that you're just keeping one column of the data out of three because it doesn't know how to handle `colClasses` of `"NULL"`. Note your NULL is in quotation marks.

An example:

```
write.csv(data.frame(fi=letters[1:3],
                            fy=rnorm(3,500,1),
                            fo=rnorm(3,50,2))
,file="a.csv",row.names = F)

write.csv(data.frame(fib=letters[2:4],
                     fyb=rnorm(3,5,1),
                     fob=rnorm(3,50,2))
          ,file="b.csv",row.names = F)

file_list=list("a.csv","b.csv")

lapply(file_list, read.csv,sep=',', header = F, col.names=F, nrow=1, colClasses = c('character', 'NULL', 'NULL'))
```

Which results in:

```
[[1]]
  FALSE.
1     fi

[[2]]
  FALSE.
1    fib

Warning messages:
1: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  cols = 1 != length(data) = 3
```

Which is the same as if you used:

```
lapply(file_list, read.csv,sep=',', header = F, col.names=F,
 nrow=1, colClasses = c('character', 'asdasd', 'asdasd'))
```

But the warning goes away (and you get the rest of the row as a result) if you do:

```
lapply(file_list, read.csv,sep=',', header = F, col.names=F,
  nrow=1, colClasses = c( 'character',NULL, NULL))
```

You can see where errors and warnings come from in source code for a function by entering, for example, `read.table` directly without anything following it, then searching for your particular warning within it.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. Is there a better solution than the one I have already used? I do not want to suppress all warning messages just yet.

Comment: `col.names` is not binary (T/F) like you have above: it is "a vector of optional names for the variables" according to the help. Get rid of `col.names=F,`, and continue using `"NULL"` in quotation marks for the columns you don't want.